# How can I access the text generated dynamically within <td> in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I tried using xpath as below:

```
Webelement req=driver.findElement(by.xpath("//[@id="leftcolumn"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]");
req.getText();
System.out.println(req.getText());
```

which shows error...due to the double quotes in "leftcolumn" 
Can anyone provide a solution for this..

Comment: Provide the complete HTML code of the page, or link to it if it is public.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes for the id value:

```
 Webelement req=driver.findElement(by.xpath("//[@id='leftcolumn']/table/tbody/tr/td[2]");
```

Comment: I tried using single quotes but it doesnt works,unable to find the xpath.

Comment: your code does not compile. Single quotes fix that. If you are not finding the expected elements you need to adjust your expression.

Comment: Can you suggest any other way to access the text generated within a td tag

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quotes.

```
Webelement req=driver.findElement(by.xpath("//[@id=\"leftcolumn\"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]");
```

Answer (score 0):

I myself found the solution,i just found the td tag in the page and iterated the list.I used gettext() for fetching the text in between the td tag.